# Paint Edges and Faces separately?

Tags: edges

Is it possible to paint the edges and faces separately, so that it will look like a squared notebook , for example?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) First, create a grid mesh object then add a WireFrame modifier.

b) Then adjust thickness as you like at step (1), uncheck the "Replace Original" option at step (2), and change the "Material Offset" to 1 at step (3), this will automatical assign the second material to the edges in the material slot.
[image]

c) Now open the material panel, add two the materials to the grid mesh object. The second material automatical will assign to edges or wires due Material Offset option which we set 1 previously in WireFrame modifier.
[image]

Comment: omg! thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Nataliya Please accept the answer.

Comment: what do you mean by accepting the answer?

Comment: Nataliya, see the unlit tick icon under the up & down arrows at the left side of 3DSinghVFX's comment. Tick that and it will turn green signaling your acceptance of answer. Thereupon,  3DSinghVFX gets rewarded 50 points.